# PHP - Change string really fast

Tags: php, string, string-formatting

Ok, trying to change a string like so:

```
[topic]=2[board]=2
```

to return this instead:

```
[topic][board]=2
```

In the above situation, I'll be working with a string variable that equals `[topic]` and another string variable that equals `[topic]=2[board]=2`

But this needs to be done for all situations...  More examples follow:

```
profile[area]=account[u]=1
```

should return this:

```
profile[area][u]=1
```

In the above situation, I'll be working with a string variable that equals `profile` and another string variable that equals `profile[area]=account[u]=1`

Another example:

```
moderate[area]=groups[sa]=requests
```

Should be this:

```
moderate[area][sa]=requests
```

In the above situation, I'll be working with a string variable that equals `moderate` and another string variable that equals `moderate[area]=groups[sa]=requests`

And another:

```
[board]=1
```

Should return:

```
[board]=1
```

In the above situation, I'll be working with a string variable that equals `[board]` and another string variable that equals `[board]=1`

Basically, what it needs to be able to do, is to get rid of the text in between ONLY the text that are between the brackets of only the first and second brackets (if the second bracket exists only).  It should not effect any third, fourth, 5th brackets.  Only the first and second brackets.

Can someone please give me a hand with this?

Thanks :)

Comment: what's the source of the sting n the first place?

Comment: I hate regexes and I'm sure that's what this is gonna need.

Comment: @ Dagon - the string is coming from $_GET values from the URL.  I need to match it against a syntax that is stored in the database that tells the software what page they are on, in order to load up a certain layout.

Comment: But this can not just use the URL, because we are dealing with variables that get returned via $_GET and we need it to be more flexible than just urls.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a regular expression that works:

```
(?<=\])\=[^\[\r\n]*(?=\[)
```

http://regexr.com?2vn71

That \r\n might need to be changed to a \Z in PHP, since you won't be dealing with line breaks, but rather with the end of a string.

So, something like:

```
preg_replace("/(?<=\])\=[^\[\Z]*(?=\[)/", "", $target);
```

**Edit:**

Here's a breakdown of what's happening here:

`(?<-\])` Make sure there's a `[` character before the matched expression

`\=` Match a `=` character

`[^\[\Z]*` Match all characters until you find a `[` or the end of the string (`\Z`)

`(?=\[)` Make sure there's a `[` after the matched expression

Comment: Wow, this is GREAT.  Works a charm!  Not sure of the difference between this one and the one that BloodyWorld posted though.

Comment: I've updated it with an explanation of what the Regex is doing. Hope this helps!

Comment: Wow, I've tested this on just about every single possibility and it's flawless so far.  Thanks so much!!! :) :)

Answer (score 0):

Another regex, designed to be used with `preg_replace()`

```
preg_replace('/^([a-z]+)?(\[[a-z]+\])(.*)(\[(.*))$/Uis', '$1$2$4', $yourData);
```